# Data type mismatch in fortran

Tags: floating-point, gradient, double-precision, fortran95

I've written a rudimentary algorithm in Fortran 95 to calculate the gradient of a function (an example of which is prescribed in the code) using central differences augmented with a procedure known as Richardson extrapolation.

```
function f(n,x)
! The scalar multivariable function to be differentiated

integer :: n
real(kind = kind(1d0)) :: x(n), f

f = x(1)**5.d0 + cos(x(2)) + log(x(3)) - sqrt(x(4))

end function f
!=====!
!=====!
!=====!

program gradient
!==============================================================================!
! Calculates the gradient of the scalar function f at x=0using a finite        !
! difference approximation, with a low order Richardson extrapolation.         !
!==============================================================================!

parameter (n = 4, M = 25)
real(kind = kind(1d0)) :: x(n), xhup(n), xhdown(n), d(M), r(M), dfdxi, h0, h, gradf(n)

h0 = 1.d0
x  = 3.d0

! Loop through each component of the vector x and calculate the appropriate
! derivative
do i = 1,n
! Reset step size
h = h0

    ! Carry out M successive central difference approximations of the derivative
do j = 1,M
        xhup = x
        xhdown = x
        xhup(i) = xhup(i) + h
        xhdown(i) = xhdown(i) - h
        d(j) = ( f(n,xhup) - f(n,xhdown) ) / (2.d0*h)
    h = h / 2.d0
    end do

    r = 0.d0
    do k = 3,M      r(k) = ( 64.d0*d(k) - 20.d0*d(k-1) + d(k-2) ) / 45.d0
        if ( abs(r(k) - r(k-1)) < 0.0001d0 ) then
        dfdxi = r(k)
            exit
        end if
    end do

    gradf(i) = dfdxi
end do

! Print out the gradient
write(*,*) " "
write(*,*) " Grad(f(x)) = "
write(*,*) " "
do i = 1,n
    write(*,*) gradf(i)
end do

end program gradient
```

In single precision it runs fine and gives me decent results.  But when I try to change to double precision as shown in the code, I get an error when trying to compile claiming that the assignment statement

```
d(j) = ( f(n,xhup) - f(n,xhdown) ) / (2.d0*h)
```

is producing a type mismatch `real(4)/real(8)`.  I have tried several different declarations of double precision, appended every appropriate double precision constant in the code with `d0`, and I get the same error every time.  I'm a little stumped as to how the function `f` is possibly producing a single precision number.

Comment: I won't even try to debug a Fortran code which does not state `implicit none` within every scope. I suggest you enhance your code and edit your question once you've done so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that f is not explicitely defined in your main program, therefore it is implicitly assumed to be of single precision, which is the type real(4) for gfortran.

I completely agree to the comment of High Performance Mark, that you really should use `implicit none` in all your fortran code, to make sure all object are explicitely declared. This way, you would have obtained a more appropriate error message about f not being explicitely defined.

Also, you could consider two more things:

- Define your function within a module and import that module in the main program. It is a good practice to define all subroutines/functions within modules only, so that the compiler can make extra checks on number and type of the arguments, when you invoke the function.
- You could (again in module) introduce a constant for the precicision and use it everywhere, where the kind of a real must be specified. Taking the example below, by changing only the line

  ```
  integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)
  ```

  into

  ```
  integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0)
  ```

  you would change all your real variables from double to single precision. Also note the `_dp` suffix for the literal constants instead of the `d0` suffix, which would automatically adjust their precision as well.

  ```
  module accuracy
    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)

  end module accuracy


  module myfunc
    use accuracy
    implicit none

  contains

    function f(n,x)
      integer :: n
      real(dp) :: x(n), f
      f = 0.5_dp * x(1)**5 + cos(x(2)) + log(x(3)) - sqrt(x(4))
    end function f

  end module myfunc


  program gradient
    use myfunc
    implicit none

    real(dp) :: x(n), xhup(n), xhdown(n), d(M), r(M), dfdxi, h0, h, gradf(n)
    :

  end program gradient
  ```

Comment: Thankyou very much, that cleared up my issue.  And I know it is good practice to use `implicit none` in Fortran, but coming from a Matlab background it's something I've had to get accustomed to and sometimes don't make use of.