# gfortran 4.8.0 bug? Return type mismatch of function

Tags: gfortran

I just use gfortran 4.1.2 and gfortran 4.8.0 to compile the following simple code:

```
function foo(a, b) result(res)

    integer, intent(in) :: a, b
    integer res

    res = a+b

end function foo

program test

    integer a, b, c

    c = foo(a, b)

end program test
```

gfortran 4.1.2 succeeds, but gfortran 4.8.0 gives the weird error:

```
test.F90:14.11:

    c = foo(a, b)
           1
Error: Return type mismatch of function 'foo' at (1) (REAL(4)/INTEGER(4))
```

Any idea?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446397/data-type-mismatch-in-fortran#comment23592695_16446397

Comment: Thanks @Mark! I am writing a tool for scanning Fortran codes and building them, this is just a test. And I am more familiar with `module`. Personally, I add `implicit none` in every code of my Fortran project, but forget to add it in the test! And I also need to declare function `foo` in the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in your code, namely that you don't specify the return type of the function foo in the main program. Per the Fortran implicit typing rules it thus gets a type of default real.

You should (1) always use 'implicit none', furthermore if at all possible, (2) use modules or contained procedures thus giving you explicit interfaces.

The reason why GFortran 4.1 doesn't report this error is that older versions of GFortran always functioned in a 'procedure at a time' mode; thus the compiler is happily oblivious to any other functions in the same file. Newer versions work in 'whole file' mode (default since 4.6) where the compiler 'sees' all the procedures in a file at a time. This allows the compiler to catch errors such as the one in your code, and also provides some optimization opportunities.

Comment: Yes, you got it! See my comment above. Thanks for clarify the rule of Fortran!