# Using Fortran 77 subprogram as stand-alone, calling from C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, fortran

So I've been avoiding Fortran like the plague, but finally my time has come... I need to take part of someone else's Fortran code (let's call it program A) and do two things with it:

(1) Merge it with a third person's Fortran code (let's call it program B) so that B can call A

(2) Merge it with my C++ code (program C) so that C can call A

B and C are optimization algorithms, and A is a collection of benchmark functions... But before all that awesomeness can happen, I must first compile the portion of A that I need. All the subroutines of A that I need are contained in one file. I've been getting it into shape based on information I got online (e.g. adding "IMPLICIT NONE" to the code and making it suitable for gfortran). But I've got two stubborn bugs and a warning (I'll leave the warning for another post).

Here's how I am currently compiling it (via a Makefile):

```
all:
    gfortran progA.FOR
    g++ -c progC.cpp
    g++ -o Program.out progA.o progC.o
    rm *.o
```

But the first line fails to complete with the following errors,

**FIRST ERROR:**

```
SUBROUTINE TP1(MODE)
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

RELEVANT CODE (starting from the top of the file):

```
      IMPLICIT NONE  
      INTEGER    NMAX,MMAX,LMAX,MNNMAX,LWA,LIWA,LACTIV,N,NILI,NINL,
     /           NELI,NENL,NEX, MODE              
      PARAMETER (NMAX   = 101, 
     /           MMAX   = 50, 
     /           LMAX   = 50, 
     /           MNNMAX = NMAX + NMAX + MMAX + 2,
     /           LWA    = 2*NMAX*NMAX + 33*NMAX + 10*MMAX + 200,
     /           LIWA   = MMAX + NMAX + 150,
     /           LACTIV = 2*MMAX + 15)  
      LOGICAL    INDEX1,INDEX2

      SUBROUTINE TP1(MODE)      
      COMMON/L1/N,NILI,NINL,NELI,NENL   
      COMMON/L2/X(2)   
      COMMON/L4/GF(2)   
      COMMON/L6/FX      
      COMMON/L9/INDEX1  
      COMMON/L10/INDEX2 
      COMMON/L11/LXL    
      COMMON/L12/LXU    
      COMMON/L13/XL(2)  
      COMMON/L20/LEX,NEX,FEX,XEX(2)     
      REAL*8 X,G,GF,GG,FX,XL,XU,FEX,XEX 
      LOGICAL LXL(2),LXU(2),LEX 
      GOTO (1,2,3,4,4),MODE     
1     N=2       
      NILI=0    
      NINL=0    
      NELI=0    
      NENL=0    
      X(1)=-2.D0
      X(2)=1.D0 
      LXL(1)=.FALSE.    
      LXL(2)=.TRUE.     
      LXU(1)=.FALSE.    
      LXU(2)=.FALSE.    
      XL(2)=-1.5D0      
      LEX=.TRUE.
      NEX=1     
      XEX(1)=1.D0       
      XEX(2)=1.D0       
      FEX=0.D0  
      RETURN    
2     FX=100.D0*(X(2)-X(1)**2)**2+(1.D0-X(1))**2
      RETURN    
3     GF(2)=200.D0*(X(2)-X(1)**2)       
      GF(1)=-2.D0*(X(1)*(GF(2)-1.D0)+1.D0)      
4     RETURN    
      END
```

I do not understand why this error appears since there are over 300 other subroutines declared exactly the same way (e.g. SUBROUTINE TP2(MODE), ..., SUBROUTINE TP300(MODE) ).

**SECOND ERROR:**

```
HX=TP273A(X)
1
Error: Return type mismatch of function 'tp273a' at (1) (REAL(4)/REAL(8))
```

RELEVANT CODE:

```
      SUBROUTINE TP273(MODE) 
      COMMON/L1/N,NILI,NIML,NELI,NENL 
      COMMON/L2/X 
      COMMON/L4/GF 
      COMMON/L6/FX 
      COMMON/L11/LXL 
      COMMON/L12/LXU 
      COMMON/L20/LEX,NEX,FEX,XEX 
      LOGICAL LEX,LXL(6),LXU(6) 
      REAL*8 X(6),FX,GF(6),FEX,XEX(6),HX,DFLOAT
      GOTO (1,2,3,4,4)MODE 
 1    N=6 
      NILI=0 
      NINL=0 
      NELI=0 
      NENL=0 
      DO 6 I=1,6 
      X(I)=0.D+0 
      XEX(I)=0.1D+1 
      LXL(I)=.FALSE. 
6     LXU(I)=.FALSE. 
      LEX=.TRUE. 
      NEX=1 
      FEX=0.D+0 
      RETURN 
 2    HX=TP273A(X) 
      FX=0.1D+2*HX*(0.1D+1+HX) 
      RETURN 
 3    HX=TP273A(X) 
      DO 7 I=1,6 
 7    GF(I)=0.2D+2*(0.16D+2-DFLOAT(I))*(X(I)-0.1D+1) 
     1       *(0.1D+1+0.2D+1*HX) 
 4    RETURN 
      END       

      REAL*8 FUNCTION TP273A (X) 
      REAL*8 X(6),DFLOAT
      TP273A=0 
      DO 10 I=1,6 
10    TP273A=TP273A+(0.16D+2-DFLOAT(I))*(X(I)-0.1D+1)**2 
      RETURN
      END
```

After reading [Physics Forums](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=696187) I tried renaming the variable "TP273A" to "TP273Avar" so that it would not have the same name as the function. This did not resolve the error. Also, I replaced the "1" with "F" just below "7  GF(I) = ..." and recompiled. Nothing changed. I'm pretty sure the changes I just mentioned are necessary anyway, but there must be something else going on.

I have also read [Data type mismatch in fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446397/data-type-mismatch-in-fortran#comment23592695_16446397) and [Function return type mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741252/function-return-type-mismatch), so I naively tried adding "module mycode" to the top and "end module mycode" to the bottom of the file to no avail.

After this is all said and done, my goal is to call these subroutines from C++ using a code similar to:

```
#include <kitchensink>

extern"C"
{
void TP1_(int *mode);
}

int main()
{
    TP1_(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Once the Fortran Code compiles, I want to modify the subroutines so that C++ can pass std::vector  X to TP#_(2,*X,*Y) and get back the computed value for Y. My std::vector X will replace COMMON/L2 X in each of the subroutines, and Y will be the value of FX computed in the subroutines. I used [Mixing Fortran and C](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMixingFortranAndC.html) as guidance for the above C++ code.

As for the B calls A part, I hope that it will be as simple as compiling A along with B, and adding "CALL TP1(MODE)" lines wherever I need them.

Any and all guidance will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Not answering your question directly, but: Fortran is not plague, it's just a language, and an easy one compared to C++. If you need to modify Fortran code, I would strongly advise you to learn a bit of it first: [here](http://www.star.le.ac.uk/%7Ecgp/prof77.pdf) is a good introduction to Fortran 77, and [here](http://www.fh-jena.de/~kleine/history/languages/ansi-x3dot9-1978-Fortran77.pdf) is the Fortran 77 standard (Fortran 77 is not the latest version available, but you seem to be using it here).

Comment: You're right. It's just that 90% of my experiences with Fortran involved what I consider to be poorly written code, so every time someone says "here's some Fortran code for you to use" I shudder.

Comment: I would disagree with @arbautjc, though my job involves a lot of Fortran. Fortran 95/2003 are fine (sometimes easier than C), but I avoid Fortran 77 like the plague! I've seen well-written Fortran 77 routines, but they are rare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have statements just in a file outside of a compilation unit. These can be subroutines, functions, modules or programs. In your case you have some statements( first of them being `implicit none`) and only after them there is the beginning of the subroutine TP1.

Either organize the procedures in a module and leave the common part before the `contains` section (more work with the C++ interoperability will follow if you are a Fortran newbie) or you must include the `implicit none` and others in every subroutine separately. Are you sure you even need this if the code worked before?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am new to Fortran. As suggested, I wrapped the program in: MODULE herp { IMPLICIT NONE and ending with INDEX2 } CONTAINS { the rest, starting with SUBROUTINE TP1(MODE)...} END MODULE herp ( {} for clarity). Now, despite the fact that "MODE" is listed in the integer declaration inside the module, I get 25+ errors saying "Symbol 'mode' has no IMPLICIT type." It does not seem do that with any other variable (but compiler gives up after 25 errors). As for your question: this code works within the context of a larger program that I can't merge with B or C. Your thoughts?

Comment: Please let me know if you see that I tagged you in this reply. I'm learning how to use Stackoverflow's features as well :)

Comment: As `MODE` is a dummy argument (aka. parameter) of the subroutine, it must be declared inside it. Whatever you declared with the same name in an upper (i.e., module) scope, it is shadowed and not accessible inside the subroutine. BTW, any comments to user's answers appear in their inbox, don't worry.

Comment: I want to add that your second problem could be fixed by putting TP273A in a module and using it from there. The problem is that, the first time that TP273A is encountered, its type has not been declared, so it automatically gets declared single-precision real! This is because Fortran will choose a type for you if you forget a declaration. To prevent this, put `implicit none` at the beginning of every module, and every function or subroutine outside a module. Using `implicit none` is Safe Programming in Fortran 101. Edit: accidentally hit enter too early.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just declare `REAL*8 TP273A` at the top of `TP273`, which declares the return type of the function, and is slightly faster than using a module. But you should definitely learn to use modules if you use Fortran for any length of time.

Comment: To @SeanPatrickSantos and Vladimir F, after using the module solution and implicit none, I keep on getting the "Symbol 'foo' has no IMPLICIT type" for dozens of other variables. Some of those are listed in COMMON blocks and others are not. My next question is: given that I can't compile with these errors, how on earth did the original author get away with it? Do the Intel compilers really let things like this go (the lack of TP273A declaration, etc, etc, etc)?

Comment: My guess is that the Intel compiler *does* work with this somehow. I've found that code that has only ever been compiled with Intel is often difficult to make work with other compilers. Fortran is designed so that it can be compiled easily with a single pass, but if Intel does some kind of look-ahead, it may fix the type for you. Or still do the wrong thing, but silently. Furthermore, the use of implicit types (which break after `implicit none`) is technically valid Fortan; it's just very bad practice.

Comment: I should add that I've seen a program randomly fail with the Intel compiler because it allowed a function that returned a double to assign that double to a single precision real, but the extra bytes ended up overwriting other memory in an unrelated part of the problem. So that's what I mean by Intel silently doing the wrong thing.